# Invariance of integral under shifting for non-continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove that if $f(x)$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{a-d}^{b-d}f(x+d)dx$

If $f(x)$ were continuous, this would be easy to prove via the change of variables theorem for definite integrals, which is a corollary of the fundamental theorem of calculus. But since $f$ is not continuous, I cannot invoke the fundamental theorem and subsequently I can't use the change of variables theorem. How can I prove this result for integrable functions?

Comment: Put the Riemann sums for the first and second integral into 1-1 correspondence

Comment: Having new variable to be continuosly differentiable bijection of the old is enough, you don't need anything about function under integral for it - Riemann integral sums are the same.